# Laravel - routing to a folder inside "views"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I'm still new to laravel and learning my way through.
Normally, for example, if I want to access the file "login.blade.php" (located in "views" folder), the route would normally be:

```
Route::get('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
```

So the above works just fine. But what if I want to have folders inside the "views" folder? For example, I want to route the file "login.php".

```
- views 
 -- account 
  --- login.blade.php
```

I tried using:

```
Route::get('/account/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
```

But I get an error saying "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException"

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You're confusing the route with the view file that your controller's action will render.

Comment: Inside `AuthController::getLogin()` you would use `$this->layout->content = View::make('account/login');`

Comment: can i see Controllers code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding on routes and views is not correct.

The first parameter of `Route::get` is the route URI which will be used in your url as `domainname.com/routeURI` and second parameter can be an `array()` or `closure function` or a string like `'fooController@barAction'`. And `Route::get()` has nothing to do with rendering views. Routes and Views are not that closely coupled as you think.

**This can be done by closures like below**

```
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', function()
{
    return View::make('account.login');
}));
```

**Or with controller action**

Route file:

```
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
```

AuthController file:

```
public function getLogin()
{
    return View::make('account.login');
}
```

You can find more at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing or If you prefer video tutorials, go to http://laracasts.com

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you very much! Now I understand, and it's even nicer that I can use Controller functions so this way I can filter.

Comment: @EthanMcKee welcome. Almost everything on laravel holds single responsibility. Its such a beauty.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write following code in AuthController.php Controller

```
public function getLogin()
{
      return View::make("account.login");
}
```